# Gtk#-2.99.x for Windows

Tags: c#, .net, gtk3, gtk#

I'm currently working on porting my application to Gtk#-3 and have done so on linux. Are there any installers for Gtk#-3 (2.99.x) for windows? Installing Gtk+3 on Windows is no problem, since there are already binaries there, but for Gtk#3 I couldn't find something. Has anybody tried this already?

Thanks for your help.
Sven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precisely this weekend, Bertrand Lorentz has fixed the generation of the MSI file in [gtk-sharp master](https://github.com/mono/gtk-sharp/commit/c9c2d099ba2cab0b9004f3e865cc1a046906f18c) (gtk#-3). So, either ask him for the file, or build it yourself, or wait for the new release.

Comment: I see Bertrand Lorentz is working on this, this is fine :). Thanks for the information ;).

Comment: Link to Windows installer: [here](https://download.gnome.org/binaries/win32/gtk-sharp/2.99/gtk-sharp-2.99.3.msi)